# Infinite Marbles in a Jar with Known Distribution

Tags: probability, combinations

Let's say I have infinite number of marbles in a jar and $90\%$ of them are red and $10\%$ are green.

If I pick $25$ out of the jars (with or without replacement probably doesn't matter because the jar has infinite number of marbles), and what's the probability that $13$ or more are red?

I have come up with:
$$p = 0.9^{13} \times 0.1^{12} + 0.9^{14} \times 0.1^{11} + \cdots + 0.9^{24} \times 0.1 + 0.9^{25}$$

Questions:

1. Is it correct?
2. Is there a way to generalize the expression above so that it can be crunched in a calculator easily?

I have seen a similar post but the answer hasn't been accepted:
[Probability of picking marbles from a bag with only the ratio of marbles given](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803280/probability-of-picking-marbles-from-a-bag-with-only-the-ratio-of-marbles-given)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's right (hard to read) because you are missing a counting factor. If we take 25 marbles, then we can imagine that these are 25 spots, and we need to count the number of ways to place 13 red ones. There are $\binom{25}{13}$ ways to do that. Since there are an infinite number of marbles, the probabilities stay the same after each draw. So the chance of choose 13 reds in 25 tries is
$$\binom{25}{13}(.9)^{13}(.1)^{25-13}.$$

You can do similarly for $14, \dotsc, 25$, and since the events are disjoint, you can add up the probabilities,
$$\sum_{k = 13}^{25}\binom{25}{k}(.9)^{k}(.1)^{25-k}.$$

In this case, the number of reds in 25 draws follows a binomial distribution with parameters $n = 25, p=.9$.

If we draw $n$ marbles, and we want to compute the chance of drawing at least $k$ reds, $0\leq k\leq n$, then we have
$$\sum_{j = k}^{n}\binom{n}{j}(.9)^{j}(.1)^{n-j}.$$

Comment: Good catch for the counting factor!  It is just a bit hard to crunch into a calculator.  Is there another way to express that is easier to crunch in?  Thanks!

Comment: No, not that I can think of. Do you have to code this or something? There are probably packages that have the binomial coefficient available. It shouldn't be hard. Especially if you are using `R`.

Comment: Further, if you just need to compute it, you can actually type it up in $\LaTeX$/MathJax and input it into [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=\sum_{k+%3D+13}^{25}\binom{25}{k}%28.9%29^{k}%28.1%29^{25-k}). If you are trying to use a graphing calculator, or something like that, idk good luck.